# jquery datepicker css styling disabled dates

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to use the Jquery datepicker with a MySQL database to show any dates that have events.

I have set **showOtherMonths: true** because of preference.

What I would like to do is style the disabled dates that are in the current month so they are not the same colour as the dates in the other months.

how can I add the styles for this?

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var selected_dates = new Array();
    // get all the events from the database using AJAX
    selected_dates = getSelectedDates();

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-m-d',
        inline: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        beforeShowDay: function (date)
        {
            // get the current month, day and year
            // attention: the months count start from 0 that's why you'll need +1 to get the month right
            var mm = date.getMonth() + 1, 
                dd = date.getDate(),    
                yy = date.getFullYear();
            var dt = yy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;

            if(typeof selected_dates[dt] != 'undefined')
            {
                // put a special class to the dates you have events for so you can distinguish it from other ones
                // the "true" parameter is used so we know what are the dates that are clickable
                return [true, " my_class"];
            }

            return [false, ""];
        }           
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the css def

```
.ui-datepicker-other-month.ui-state-disabled:not(.my_class) span{
    color: red;    
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4PWqK/)

Comment: Thanks Arun.  I just took out :not (.my_class) and changed the background colour instead and i got the result i wanted.  As gibberish asked, where did you get that info from as I need to do some more styling?

Answer (score 0):

I added the code below to the custom Style.css and it works like a charm.

```
.ui-datepicker-unselectable .ui-state-default {
    background: yellow;
    color: red;
}
```